# 301 редирект на страницы без слешей в конце и убрать один уровень каталога

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Незнаю как настроить 301 редирект со страниц сайта с одним, двумя и более слешами на страницу без слешей например:

С

```
http://site_name.ru// 
http://site_name.ru/// 
...

http://site_name.ru/какаянибудьстраница//
http://site_name.ru/какаянибудьстраница///
...
```

на

```
http://site_name.ru
```

и еще нужно сократить каталог:

С

```
http://site_name.ru/katalog/категориятовара/какойнибудьтовар
```

на

```
http://site_name.ru/категориятовара/какойнибудьтовар
```

Заранее благодарен!